# Alternative or Explanation as approved answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Frequently, when asking a question about whether something is allowed, or guaranteed to work. The answers can be split up in two categories:

- Explanations, containing the reason something is or isn't allowed.
- Alternative solutions, stating the approach is illegal, or bad practice. And offering a solution.

Ideally of course an answer contains both. But more often than not this does not happen. In that case, what should I do?

- Change, or request a change to either of the answers so they contain both the explanation and an alternative.
- Accept the explanation. This is technically the best answer.
- Accept the alternative. Although this might not be a direct answer to the question. However, the better alternative is at least as, if not more relevant, than the explanation. Since this is the bit you need trying to avoid doing illegal things and avoid bad practices.
- Change the question to include the explanation why something is illegal and ask for an alternative. And accept the alternative.

For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121194/is-it-safe-to-use-the-structure-dereference-operator-on-the-result-of-stda) question illustrates my dilemma quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are free to accept the answer you personally deem most helpful.  It doesn't matter how you judge that.  If you really can't decide you can also not accept any answer (in this case I would recommend commenting on the answers on what else you're looking for).  I would hesitate to edit the question too much since the answers were answering the question as you posted it, but you can still edit it if you really feel your current question isn't what you're actually wanting to know.

Remember that besides accepting, you are free to vote on the helpfulness of answers (it sounds like you found both helpful, so upvotes are appropriate).